# How to record who uses java program

Tags: java, hitcounter

I was wondering if there is a way to record who runs your program. Currently I have been using htmlunit, but that puts an extra 10MB on the program that's only 700KB.

The reason I want to know the programs usage Anonymously is because this will be my first "release" of a program and I wanted to know how well it's doing and how often its ran.

When I use htmlunit, I record information by loading a website that has a google analytics script on it so it activates the script and google records it.

Is there a better way to do this other than using htmlunit, because like I said, it puts an unnecessary 10MB on the program

Comment: Side note: be sure to inform users that you are collecting anonymous usage statistics. Personally, i would ask them if they want to enable anonymous usage stats sending at install time, and leave an option in the app preferences to check/uncheck this

Comment: Right, I could implement a checkbox that allows to send annonymous usage statistics, or not. And It's meant to be anonymous

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah but i think the OP didn't mean really _who_, as he written _I wanted to know how well it's doing and how often its ran_ and _I record information by loading a website that has a google analytics script on it so it activates the script and google records it_. You don't have to know who is using the application if you want to know how often it's launched, and also Google Analytics doesn't provide detailed informations about the pc on which the script is ran, in both cases it would be anonymous

Comment: @Loligans: FWIW, I can **totally** understand the desire to do this. But I'd resist it if you can. Just ask people to contact you with good and bad feedback. Best,

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Why should I resist? (not trying to bash you or anything) It just seems like knowing how well a program is doing on the internet is a good thing?

Comment: @Loligans: Absolutely. *Monitoring* people's usage, though, is a good way to prevent uptake.

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily do this and also run the analytics javascripts.  You can host a small page on a website somewhere that records a hit pretty easily.

You can try using [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) instead of HTMLUnit, but that still adds quite a bit of overhead.  You can also do this in pure JRE using [URL.openConnection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29).

Comment: How would I implement the webpage to record a hit? I thought that requires Javascript?

Comment: Only if you are set on using the Google Analytics, which seems to be overkill for a "how many times has this been launched" counter.  I'd just add a dummy .html page, and count how many times it's been hit by looking at the web log.  You could also create a web page that puts hit statistics into a database, and provide visualization of the hit stats too. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was I used an online service which gave me a php script. I then opened a URL connection and pulled some data and the server recorded it as a hit.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    URL page1 = new URL("Link to your PHP script goes here.");//URL goes here
    URLConnection openConnection1= page1.openConnection();    //Open the connection to be able to connect
    openConnection1.connect();//Actually Connect to the host
    openConnection1.getHeaderFields();//Information gathered (to activate the PHP script)
}
```